# Can't change from Desktop kit to Android kit

Tags: android, c++, qt

When I try to change from Desktop kit to Android kit, this message pops up

> kit desktop qt 5.4.0 mingw 32bit is incompatible with kit android for
>   armeabilv7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.4.0)

I added the SDK, NDK and the android kit is added to the kits section.
I can't understand what's wrong. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: if you know how to setup the desktop kit, i'll advice you to delete/remove the desktop kit and see if you can use the android kit before setting up the desktop kit again. Also, check to see if you're not using mingw compiler for the android kit.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve this problem

1. You can use the maintenance tool in the Qt directory folder to update or add the components needed to be compatible with the desktop kit.
2. You can uninstall then reinstall Qt but during installation check all the components in the extra tools and android tools

after doing one of the above 2 solutions (i prefer the second one) add the android kit from Projects > Add kit, then you can use it smoothly...thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have created your app for the desktop first and now you want to try it on Android.

If so please follow these steps:

- Click on "Projects" to open the project view.
- Click on "Add Kit"
- Select the desired kit

Now you have 2 Kits.
You may click on the Kit that is not required anymore and select "Remove Kit"

Done!